# Settings source precedence in jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

In a jQuery plugin, I can instantiate it from existing HTML, construct the HTML from a dummy node with "data-" attributes, or generate the HTML from scratch using settings passed to the constructor method (merged with defaults).

Basically, there are three sources of settings.  1. Default "settings" object in the class. 2.  Settings object passed to the constructor.  3. Data attributes on an existing HTML node, on which we'll call the plugin.

Should "data-" attributes take precedence over attributes passed to the function?  I'm really interested in whether or not there's a recommended practice and what reasoning there is behind it, if any.

I think parameters passed to the function should almost act like secondary defaults, so that the existing HTML node's data takes precedence.

Comment: Have a look though the [jquery boilerplate](http://jqueryboilerplate.com/). These are typically "best practice" if such a thing exists. Remember one man's best practice is another man's hideous hack

Comment: That's helpful.  I can see that they basically do what I thought it should.  They call 'extend' to merge the passed settings with the defaults (into a new object), so the passed settings function like default overrides.  They then leave it up to the developer in the 'init' method, saying "Place initialization logic here. You already have access to the DOM element and the options via the instance, e.g. this.element and this.settings."

Comment: As an open question, however, I'm still curious if anyone has any logical argument for why, given settings passed to the method and settings on the operational node, one should override the other.  For example, in stylesheets, attributes values on the node override inherited styles.